# How to serialise model field verbose_name

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

I want to create a generic ListView template that I can use with any model.

I am currently using this approach to create a `dict` of field names and values:

views.py

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize( "python", SomeModel.objects.all() )
```

template.html

```
{% for instance in data %}
    {% for field, value in instance.fields.items %}
        {{ field }}: {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will return the field but not the field `verbose_name`. E.g on a user model `is_active` does not return as `Is the user active?`.

Is there any way to also serialise the verbose name?

Comment: in shell try `dir(obj)` where `obj` is `SomeModel`'s object

Comment: @ShashankSingh thanks, how does that help this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following which was inspired from `django.forms.model_to_dict`.

It retrieves the fields from the given queryset's model then iterates through the queryset and uses `.values_from_object()` to retrieve the field's value for each instance.

The key is determined using `f.verbose_name` instead of `f.name`.

```
from itertools import chain

def queryset_to_dict(queryset, include=None, exclude=None):
    """
    :param queryset: queryset of objects
    :param include: return only the named fields in each instance dict
    :param exclude: exclude the named from the instance dict even if listed in `fields`
    :return: list of dicts
    """
    opts = queryset.model._meta
    fields = []
    for f in chain(opts.concrete_fields, opts.private_fields, opts.many_to_many):
        if not getattr(f, 'editable', False):
            continue
        if include is not None and f.name not in include:
            continue
        if exclude and f.name in exclude:
            continue

        fields.append(f)

    data = []
    for instance in queryset:
        instance_dict = {}
        for f in fields:
            key = f.verbose_name
            instance_dict[key] = f.value_from_object(instance)

        data.append(instance_dict)

    return data
```

Sample usage:

```
queryset = Order.objects.filter(date_invoice__gte='2019-12-01')
data = queryset_to_dict(queryset, include=['id', 'date_invoice'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a model to a dictionary and retain all `ForiegnKey` model relationships. I used the following:

**Without Verbose Name**

```py
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1) # EXAMPLE

instance_dict = {key: getattr(instance, key) for key in model_to_dict(instance).keys()}
```

*Output*

```py
{'foreign_key': [<OtherModel: OtherModel object>],
 'id': 1,
 'many_to_many': [<OtherModel: OtherModel object>],
 'normal_value': 1}
```

> This can be useful if you want to display the `__str__()` value in your template for foreign key relationships.

> Including keyword arguments `fields=` and `exclude=` into `model_to_dict(instance, [...])` enables you to filter specific fields.

**With Verbose Name**

```py
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1) # EXAMPLE

instance_dict = {instance._meta.get_field(key).verbose_name if hasattr(instance._meta.get_field(key), 'verbose_name') else key: getattr(instance, key) for key in model_to_dict(instance).keys()}
```

*Example Output (If there were verbose names for given example)*

```py
{'Other Model:': [<OtherModel: OtherModel object>],
 'id': 1,
 'My Other Model:': [<OtherModel: OtherModel object>],
 'Normal Value:': 1}
```